# Unable to pass Custom Parameters to a Visualforce Page via URL button in Lightning Experience

Tags: custom-button, lightning-experience, bug, urlfor

I've a Custom Object whose NEW and EDIT Standard Buttons/Links have been overridden with a Visualforce Page.

This Custom Object also has couple of Record Types on it.

I've added a Custom URL Button for each RecordType so as to quickly execute the override VF page by skipping the Record Type selection page.

Now, this works fine in Classic, and it has worked fine in Lightning Experience till now. But now, I've noticed that the URL Button is not passing the custom parameters, which I've set in URL Button.

My URL Button code is this:

> {!URLFOR('/'+ $ObjectType.Custom_OBject_A__c +'/e' , null,
>   [RecordType=URLENCODE('01290000000c821'),
>   parentid=Parent_Object__c.Id], false)}

And this button has been created on **Custom_Object_A__c**.

So when this button is called from the Custom Object A's related list on Parent Object Detail View, the Visualforce Page set on the EDIT link as override opens and with custom Apex controller code, I read the "parentid" querystring parameter and populate the target field in the vf page.

This **parentid** parameter is getting passed in `Classic` but not in `Lightning Experience`.